# Transacción no funciona ASP.NET, C# y SQL N-Capas

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp

el problema que tengo es que trato de insertar un dato (beneficio), el dato se inserta (en el try) pero no sé porque brinca al catch, por tanto, en la vista se muestra el mensaje de error (que hice en la BD) devuelto por el catch pero indica que no se puede agregar porque está repetido, pero sí fue agregado. 
La tabla tiene el campo UNIQUE para evitar valores repetidos.

Tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IH_BENEFICIOS(
ID_BENEFICIO INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
NOM_BENEFICIO VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
DESCRIPCION_BENEFICIO TEXT ,
FECHA_CREACION DATE,
ID_USUARIO INT)
```

Procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROC NV_BENEFICIO(
@nomBeneficio VARCHAR(255),
@desBeneficio TEXT,
@idUsuario INT)
AS
IF(NOT EXISTS (
SELECT NOM_BENEFICIO FROM IH_BENEFICIOS WHERE NOM_BENEFICIO= @nomBeneficio) )
    INSERT INTO IH_BENEFICIOS(
    NOM_BENEFICIO,
    DESCRIPCION_BENEFICIO,
    FECHA_CREACION,
    ID_USUARIO
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
    @nomBeneficio, 
    @desBeneficio, 
    GETDATE(),
    @idUsuario 
    )
ELSE 
RAISERROR(  '¡El beneficio llamado %s ya existe en inventario !',11,1,  @nomBeneficio); GO
```

Capa Entidad:

```
    public class Beneficio
{
    public int idBeneficio { get; set; }
    public string nomBeneficio { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int idUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

Capa De Datos:

```
        public string nvBeneficio(Beneficio objBeneficio)
    {
        cn = conexion.getConexion();
        cn.Open();
        string mensaje = "";
        using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("NV_BENEFICIO", cn, tr);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("nomBeneficio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objBeneficio.nomBeneficio;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("desBeneficio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objBeneficio.descripcion;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objBeneficio.idUsuario;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tr.Commit();
                mensaje = "Se a agregado 1 beneficio !";
            }
            catch
            {
                mensaje = "Error al ingresar el beneficio !";
                tr.Rollback();
            }
            finally {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        return mensaje;
    }
```

Capa negocio:

```
public string nvBeneficio(Beneficio objBeneficio)
    {
        return cnProcedimientos.nvBeneficio(objBeneficio);
    }
```

Capa Vista:

```
 protected void btnGuardarBeneficio_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Beneficio objBeneficio = new Beneficio();
        string mensaje = "¡ Beneficio No registrado !";
        dr = objNegocio.infoMaster(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Rows[0];
        objBeneficio.nomBeneficio = txtNombreBeneficio.Value;
        objBeneficio.descripcion = txtDescripcionBeneficio.Value;
        objBeneficio.idUsuario = int.Parse(dr["ID_USUARIO"].ToString());
        mensaje = objNegocio.nvBeneficio(objBeneficio);
        vaciarControles(); // Limpio los campos tras agregar la información 
        CatalogoBeneficios(); // Lleno el GridView donde muestro los beneficios agregados
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alerta", "<script> alert('" + mensaje + "'); </script>", false);

    }
```

Noté también que la primera vez se ejecuta correctamente pero las siguientes no.
El problema me pasa con el Insert únicamente

Comment: intenta quitando el RAISERROR del procedure asi obtienes el mensaje real del problema y veras este en el Message del exception que tomas en el catch

Comment: a tus queries no le estas indicando el Begin y el END que son como los corchetes en c#  if Begin end else begin end de esa forma debes declarar tu Stored procedure. Y revisa que tu id sea autoincremental

Comment: El mensaje que me tira es de choque con el UNIQUE lo cual no tiene sentido si se inserta una vez.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    mensaje = strig.Format("Error al ingresar el beneficio ! Detalle: {0}", ex.Message);
    tr.Rollback();
}
```

para enterarte cual es la causa del problema, sino ante un problema siempre recibiras el mismo mensaje

Sino quiere devolver el mensaje al usuario al menos debes loguarlo a un archivo cuando lo capturas en el catch, por lo menos lo dejas registrado y devuelves un mensaje standar

Comment: Creo que no me doy a entender, sé bien cual es el problema, el problema es que trata de insertar un dato que ya existe en el campo NOM_BENEFICIO el cual es UNIQUE. Lo que  pasa es que entra al TRY, ingresa el dato y lo confirma con commit, luego pasa al catch y me da el error, este error que coloco se debe a que trata de ingresar el dato nuevamente en el campo marcado como UNIQUE y es eso lo raro. Además, se supone que el Rollback debería devolverlo para que no se guarde y esto no pasa, el dato queda en la BD guardado.

Comment: si estas debugeando la aplicacion puede que la transaccion se vea afectada y confirme la operacion aunque realices un roolback, intenta ejecutar la app usando el .exe directo para ver si sucede lo mismo, o quizas ejecutando pero sin breakpoint